Can I discuss topics related to a site's subject, but not suitable for a question, somewhere on Stack Exchange?
I have been using Math Stack Exchange for a while now and my experience has been pretty great. But I have faced a limitation.
On this site as we know we are only allowed to ask relevant questions and/ or answer questions of others appropriately. But I am a math enthusiast and want to keep my knowledge up to date on what is going on in the mathematics field and also ask tips and advice from other experts regarding general problem solving and preparation for various exams.
Is there a feature that allows me to ask such questions while not disrupting the flow of the site?
(I have used the example of Math Stack Exchange but I think this can be applicable for multiple other sites in the stack exchange network.)
TLDR: How can I ask questions that are officially off-topic for the site I want to participate on, but that are still somewhat related to the general topic of that site?

MSE is also Meta Stack Exchange, aka this very site, so when here, at least, use the full name.

Also, if you mean this only for Mathematics Stack Exchange it's off topic here and should be asked on the per site meta.

Is there a feature that allows me to ask such questions while not disrupting the flow of the site? Use Chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/  When on Stack Overflow: discussions: https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions

@ShadowWizardLoveZelda Thank you for pointing it out. I have made the changes.

@ShadowWizardLoveZelda Please read the note

Well there's the chat then, as @rene mentioned, and there's also this popular request.

What kind of place are you looking for, Reddit?

Your question here is unclear. Please [edit] to clarify. Your title says "discussion of non-question related topics", but you also say "that allows me to ask such questions". So, you basically said "How can I ask questions while not asking questions", which doesn't make sense. What I think you're asking is something along the lines of "How can I ask questions that are officially off-topic for the site I want to participate on, but that are still somewhat related to the general topic of that site?"

@Makyen yes that is exactly what I wanted to ask. I will make the necessary changes.

Welcome to Meta SE. Some sites have chat room(s) which at least fairly closely approximate what you're looking for. Since you specifically mention Math SE, note there's the Mathematics chat room, with a description of "Associated with Math.SE; for both general discussion & math questions alike. Just ask; don't ask to ask. Rarely if ever expressible as a ratio of integers. Chat guidelines: http://tinyurl.com/hzl2955 | $\LaTeX$ in chat: http://tinyurl.com/cfqcvpc". I suggest you check this out to see how well it might work for you.

"Is there a feature that allows me to ask such questions while not disrupting the flow of the site?" - ask what questions? In the previous paragraph, you do not describe anything that I could reasonably call a "question".

This is a legitimate question to ask. Why is it so heavily downvoted?

I'd say Stack Exchange chat, with two caveats.
Discoverability is currently terrible, with no apparent moves to fix that. This results in many chatrooms being relatively quiet and un/under utilised.
The other is - well hang out a bit and get to know the chat first, many of them have their own culture. Quite a few of the technical chatrooms don't really do 'questions' - but often talk about peripheral issues of interest. It might not be the best fit, but its worth exploring to see if there's places in the network (or others!) with similar interests .
Generally though, in chat, we don't ask questions, we talk about things -and this might help you with what you probably need, a space to share your interests
